# When and how to properly use loop optimization and transformation techniques

Tags: java, c, optimization, loops

**First of all, i would like to know what is the fundamental difference between loop optimization and transformation** , also

A simple loop in C follows:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
a[i] = b[i]*c[i];
}
```

but we can **unroll** it to:

```
for (i = 0; i < N/2; i++) 
{
a[i*2] = b[i*2]*c[i*2];
a[i*2 + 1] = b[i*2 + 1]*c[i*2 + 1];
}
```

but further we can unroll it..but what is the limit till which we can unroll it, and how do we find that.

There are many more techniques like Loop Tilling,Loop Distribution,etc. , how to determine when to use the appropriate one.

Comment: Why not let your compiler do this for you? Make sure that optimizations are enabled, and then go outside and do something fun.

Comment: how does compiler decide...out of curiosity.

Comment: @pmg it is not mine, it is from book Wayner Wolf,which a very good book

Comment: The only place this would really be worth doing is if you develop for an embedded or real-time system, and every nanosecond is important. Otherwise, it might happen that your unrolled code would run slightly faster on one specific system with one specific compiler, but become worse elsewhere when the compiler finds a better way of doing it.

Comment: @pmg-who are you to judge.? and newaz what you are saying is not correct also

Comment: ya i am talking for embedded programming, i guess that comes under programming.

Comment: there was no edit in code.....

Comment: @sum2000 ... and is this code in a part which has to run real-time, and making it half a microsecond faster would solve a problem you have? Otherwise you are looking for a fix to a non-existent problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that the OP has already profiled his/her code and has discovered that this piece of code is actually important, and actually answer the question :-) :

The compiler will try to make the loop unrolling decision based on what it knows about your code and the processor architecture.

In terms of making things faster.

- As someone pointed out, unrolling does reduce the number of loop termination condition compares and jumps.
- Depending on the architecture, the hardware may also support an efficient way to to index near memory locations (E.g., mov eax, [ebx + 4]), without adding additional instructions (this may expand to more micro-ops though - not sure).
- Most modern processors use out of order execution, to find instruction level parallelism.  This is hard to do, when the next N instructions are after multiple conditional jumps (i.e., the hardware would need to be able to discard variable levels of speculation).

  - There is more opportunity to reorder memory operations earlier so that the data fetch latency is hidden.
  - Code vectorization (e.g., converting to SSE/AVX), may also occur which allows parallel execution of the code in some cases.  This is also a form of unrolling.

In terms of deciding when to stop unrolling:

- Unrolling increases code size.  The compiler knows that there are penalties for exceeding instruction code cache size (all modern processors), trace cache(P4), loop buffer cache(Core2/Nehalem/SandyBridge), micro-op cache(SandyBridge), etc. Ideally it uses static cost-benefit heuristics (a function of the specic code and architecture) to determine which level of unrolling will result in the best overall net performance. Depending on the compiler, the heurstics may vary (often I find that it would be nice to tweak this oneself).

  - Generally, if the loop contains a large amount of code it is less likely to be unrolled because the loop cost is already amortized, there is plenty of ILP available, and the code bloat cost of unrolling is excessive.  For smaller pieces of code, the loop is likely to be unrolled, since the cost is likely to be low.  The actual number of unrolls will depend on the specifics of the architecture, compiler heuristics and code, and will be what the compiler decides is optimal (it may not be :-) ).

In terms of when YOU should be doing these optimizations:

- When you don't think the compiler did the correct thing.  The compiler may not be sophisticated (or sufficiently up to date) enough to use the knowledge of the architecture you are working on optimally.
- Possibly, the heuristics just failed (they are just heuristics after all).  In general, if you know the piece of code is very important, try unroll it, and if it improved performance, keep it, otherwise throw it out.  Also, only do this when you have roughly the whole system in place, since what may be beneficial, when your code working set is 20k, may not be beneficial when your code working set is 31k.

Comment: This answer is correct so far as it goes. But I feel compelled to point out that if you're really dealing with a compiler that isn't doing the correct thing and is not sophisticated or sufficiently up to date, you should *update that compiler*. :-)

Comment: Not always an option.  Whenever a new architectural feature comes out, it takes a long time for the compiler technology to evolve to support it optimally.   Also, often the compiler technology never gets there.  As a small example, if I have a ~100 uop loop in which 99.99 of the application is spent, I want it unwound to the size of my upop cache on a SB architecture (I.e. 15x) even with PGO this won't happen.

Comment: @Crowley9 Even with ICC that was told to optimize for sb? I would've thought they'd do a better job there, but certainly - if you have external knowledge about your application you can help the compiler. You just have to understand enough about architectures to know when the compiler didn't do the right thing which isn't such a simple thing in this day and age. I.e. how many programmers know about µop caches?

Comment: @Voo: yup, I never said it was easy.  :-). When doing optimization at this level it really helps to have a good understanding of what the underlying architecture is doing to avoid wasting time.  That said though, the programmer has the advantage of hindsight, and can tweak their code in order to find better performance by iteratively tweaking,measuring and conditionally rolling back.  Knowledge of the architecture just guides the tweaking process more effectively.

Answer (score 3):

This may seem rather off topic to your question but I cannot but stress the importance of this.

The key is to write a correct code and get your code working as per the requirement without being bothered about micro optimization.
If later you find your program to be lacking in performance then you **profile!!** your application to find the problem areas and then try to optimize them.
Remember as one of the wise guys said `It is only 10% of your code which runs 90% of the total run time of your application trick is to identify that code through profiling and then try to optimize it.`

Comment: The Wise guy who said it is *Scott Meyers* in his book *More Effective C++*.

Answer (score 2):

Well considering that your first attempt at optimizing is already **wrong** in 50% of all cases I really wouldn't try anything more complex (try any odd number).

Also instead of multiplying your indices, just add 2 to i and loop up to N again - avoids the unnecessary shifting (minor effect as long as we stay with powers of 2, but still)

To summarize: You created incorrect, slower code than what a compiler could do - well that's the perfect example of why you shouldn't do this stuff I assume.

Comment: Well, **then you are completely wrong**, if i could ,i would have downvoted on your answer, that optimization technique is from book Wayner Wolf, also it takes less time than original(it is tested) . If you have doubt just read about **loop unrolling** first

Comment: @sum2000 Have you *tried* the code? Saying it's correct because someone wrote it isn't a very good argument. Regardless of the original code's correctness, Voo's point is a good one. Optimizing correctly is difficult to get right, and hardly ever worth it. Let the compiler do it for you, that's what optimizing compilers are designed for. In my experience, good compilers are smarter than good programmers at least 90% of the time.

Comment: I am talking in terms of embedded computing and do you want me to refer to the book and it's page..just for confirmation, i didn't write it on my own.

Comment: Wow, I've just been referred to a Wikipedia article about loop unwinding by someone who is asking for an explanation of how it works. I should be insulted, but I'm just going to laugh.

Comment: @sum2000 So let's see. Just play it through with N=3. The original loop executes the code for i=0,1 and 2. Your "optimized version" only executes code for: i=0 and 1. Notice something? Now I'm not saying the guy got it wrong - I'm pretty sure he will mention somewhere that "Works only if N is evenly divisible by the unroll factor, otherwise we need a loop afterwards for the last iteration". About your timing claim: That just shows understanding benchmarks is hard (if it doesn't have to be correct I can make it arbitrarily fast). Adding N shifts certainly doesn't make code faster..